# How can I find Pokémon Go's uptime?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way for finding out if the Pokémon Go servers are accessible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I don't believe there is an official server status page yet, MMO Server Status now have a Pokemon GO status page:

[MMO Server Status: Pokemon GO](http://www.mmoserverstatus.com/pokemon_go)

There is another site now that is also tracking the server status:

http://cmmcd.com/PokemonGo

This site crowd sources the server status by clicking one of the UP, UNSTABLE, or DOWN buttons.

Comment: This seems accurate enough, the game is currently working for me here in NZ, and the site is reporting that it is up in NZ and AUS.

Comment: They're cache missed so the page is down. Great coincidence

Comment: Working here. Checked the status of another MMO to make sure it wasn't just local caching.

Comment: Yeah just a cache miss that happened to be at the same time

Comment: Ahh, I just saw that as well. Amusing. :)

Answer (score 6):

Although this question is already a few days old, I want to add my status page. Other than the site from cmmcd, the status is checked every 60 seconds through the Pokémon GO API. Hope you like it too. Have fun playing! :)

https://go.jooas.com/

Comment: Where did you find this Pokémon GO API? :-) I've been searching for it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well add one more... =P
Pokevision (and I) use http://ispokemongodownornot.com/.